# Supplements taken with a healthy diet and exercise regimine

Tags: supplements

Starting a 3 day a week exercises routine and I am wondering what supplements I should be taking. If you have been following my posts you can see I have posted several time already today. I am really serious about getting healthy and I am trying to avoid the beginning mistakes and really trying to maximize the benefits from the new life style right out of the gate. So this boils down to knowing how/when to eat, how to exercise and how often, and what supplements should be taken to round everything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None really if your eating 5 times a day and getting enough protein. **but**

HERE is a list of great supplements that help

- **dymatize micronized creatine monohydrate 1000 grams $19.99**
- **dymatize micronized glutamine 300 grams $15.99**
- **SciFit Beta Alanine 2000 Powder, 500 Grams $19.97**

you can find all these on bodybuilding.com under the store tab. They are great supplements, dont let anyone tell you, 'you need super 9000 creatine or nitro monster beast supplement'. The supplements i posted have been tested by consumer labs for purity and effectiveness. Plus they will last for a looooong time theres so many servings and cheap.

How to use the supplements

- **Creatine**-take 5 grams 3 times through out the day for 3 days then 3 days off. Try and take one of those doses 30 minutes before your workout and spread the doses out with 4 hours in between. Mix with 10-16 oz of water or chosen drink, do not mix with acidic drinks or cola and dont leave your dose in liquid for more than one hour.
- **Glutamine**-take 2.5 grams in the morning than 2.5 grams before you go to bed.
- **Beta-Alanine**-20 minutes before your work out.

**Creatine**- will make you gain 10 pounds in water weight real quick but its effect on strength during work outs is really helpful.

**Glutamine**- helps with so much! recovery and immune system.

**Beta Alanine**- its great for giving extra endurance and strength during workouts helping push mass and strength gains.